# Как узнать список библиотек, которые может подкючить компилятор?

Tags: c++, qt, библиотеки, компилятор

Столкнулся с возможным отсутствием одной из библиотек  `<sstream>  <vector>  <string>  <fstream>` в компиляторе MSVC2017 через Qt Creator.

В папке Tools не разобрался что к чему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я описывал проблему ошибочной сборки проекта, отвечающие предположили, что проблема связана с отсутствием линковки объектных файлов, которые содержат реализацию ненайденных символов.

Так как же проверить список дефолтных библиотек и как добавить недостающие(и где их найти)?

Comment: `<sstream>` и прочие - это не библиотеки, а заголовочные файлы. Компилятор может подключать какие угодно заголовочные файлы, стоит только сказать, где их искать. И в MSVC2017 есть все обычные заголовочные файлы `<vector>`  `<string>` и т.д.

Comment: А вообще этот вопрос похож на продолжение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/905064/Не-находит-obj-файл, "объектных файлов, которые содержат реализацию ненайденных символов" - это ваши файлы, а не библиотечные (в данном случае)

Comment: Частая ошибка при ручном редактировании *.pro файлов: пишут `INCLUDEPATH=путь_к_папке' вместо `INCLUDEPATH+=путь_к_папке'. Может проявляться именно так.